# calling operators of base class... safe?

Tags: c++, operators

Is following pattern ok/safe ? Or are there any shortcomings ?
(I also use it for equality operators)

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs)
{
    static_cast<Base&>(*this) = rhs;
    // ... copy member variables of Derived
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is fine, but it's a lot more readable IMHO to call the base-class by name:

```
Base::operator = (rhs);
```

Comment: indeed... just noticed that this notation works for implicitly defined assignement operators aswell (always thought that it would only work for explicitly defined ones)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it's safe.

A different syntax to do the same thing could be:

```
Base::operator=( rhs );
```

Comment: actually this is a better way, then needing to cast. Also, this should be done in the derived classes

Answer (score 6):

That's better to use

```
Base::operator=(rhs);
```

because if your base class have a pure virtual method the static_cast is not allowed.

```
class Base {
    // Attribute
    public:
        virtual void f() = 0;
    protected:
        Base& operator(const Base&);
}

class Derived {
    public:
        virtual void f() {};
        Derived& operator=(const Derived& src) {
            Base::operator=(src); // work
            static_cast<Base&>(*this) = src; // didn't work
        }
}
```