# Proper way to use operator = in derived class and slicing

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator, object-slicing

So I have a base class that has a private member and a derived class that also has some member, the base class defines an operator =, and this is my questions:

Is this the proper way to do this or is there a better way?
Do I commit any slicing along the way?

```
class A
{
private:
int* Arr;
public:
A(){
    Arr=new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Arr[i]=2*i;
    }
}
const A& operator=(const A& a){
    delete []Arr;
    Arr=new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Arr[i]=a.Arr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
};

class B: public A
{
private:
int * Arr2;
public:
B(){
    Arr2=new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Arr2[i]=3*i;
    }
}
const B& operator=(const B& b){
    A::operator=(b);
    delete []Arr2;
    Arr2=new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Arr2[i]=b.Arr2[i];
    }
    return *this;
}   
};
```

I know this ain't a perfect code but i just wrote a simple one for the question.

Comment: This isn't exception-safe or self-assignment-safe (this is interesting reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)..  Other than that, it looks approximately ok.

Comment: Yes I know, i have no exception-safe, self-assignment-safe prevention method.what about the other quistion? Is there any slicing done(even a safe one) in the code?

Comment: What are you hoping this line does: A::operator=(b);

Comment: @doctorlove This calls base class "=" operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734846/calling-operators-of-base-class-safe.

Comment: It calls the A assignment operator to use on the A part of the B object that needs to be copied.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue or slicing being done in this code. But why are you deleting integer array and doing new. I think you can skip those steps

Comment: Side note: Return type for operator= should be T& not const T&, or you will not be able to write a = b = c;

Comment: Yes is this case it true, but this is just an example of a much more complex code.

Comment: @Bogolt I belive you are wrong about that, is still can be done.

Comment: Why not use stl containers?

Comment: What difference will it make in the way i presented this question?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thank you for your ref it was truly insightful, I learned much from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after much research I have come to this conclusions:

While this use of the base class assignment operator will work properly

```
A::operator=(b)
```

The code will still need to provide a proper exception-safe, self-assignment-safe
guarantee as it mentioned in the comments.

Moreover since we need to implement an assignment operator that also means by the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) we will need to implement a copy-constructor and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734628/copy-constructor-and-operator-overload-in-c-is-a-common-function-possible/1734640#1734640) that will cause an unnecessary code duplication.

So how do we solve all this problems (and probably a few more..) ?
Best why I found is to use [Copy-and-Swap-Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). I believe no further explanation is needed beyond what is provided in that post.

Answer (score 0):

What you want *isn't* a hierarchy of classes. It is impossible to assign to a base object to get the properties of a derived object. The base object will always remain a base object. If you want to have polymorphic behaviour but keep sensible value semantics, encapsulate the polymorphism within a non-polymorphic class:

```
class A_impl;

class A {
public:
    //Public interface:
    //...

private:
    //Assuming `value_ptr` similar to
    //https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/17aee21522ce8d07c7a74b138e528fadf04d62ed/include/wheels/smart_ptr/value_ptr.h%2B%2B?at=default
    value_ptr<A_impl> impl;
};


class A_impl {
public:
    //Implementation interface:
    //virtual ...
    //virtual ~A_impl() {}
};

class B : public A_impl {
public:
    //Implementation:
    //...
};
```

Comment: This is actually not what i meant, I need to be able to assign derived classes into each other while making sure the base class private members get assign properly

Comment: In that case just forward to `A::operator=`, as you did in the code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

you shoud write copy construct operator.

Comment: And how
 will that help me? i want to assign an object into an existing object not to create a new one.