# Copy assignment operator for derived class

Tags: c++

I have a class B deriving from A. A implements copy constructor and assignment operator. I have copy constructor for B and want to implement assignment for B. My approach (most likely incorrect) is

```
B& B::operator=(const B& other) {
    B tmp (other);
    std::swap <A>(*this, tmp);
    std::swap (m_member, other.m_member);
}
```

Can something like this work? I have looked on the web for specializations of std::swap to a basis class but have not found something usefull.

Comment: Please make your title describe the question rather than just listing technologies

Comment: It still just names a thing, rather than asking or describing a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this stackoverflow thread ([calling operators of base class... safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734846/calling-operators-of-base-class-safe)) on how to use operator = from base class.

What I don't understand is why you are using swap. You should instead do something like this:

```
B& B::operator=(const B& other) {
    A::operator = (other);
    this->m_member = other.m_member;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: M_member can be dynamically allocated. I use the copy constructor to allocated the new memory then I am trying to swap only such that the destructor of tmp correctly frees memory.

Comment: If you are using C++ 11 try to use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr. Check out this page containing videos on unique and shared_ptr: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5jc9xFGsL8FWtnZBeTqZBbniyw0uHyaH 

Another solution is to create a private / protected method for dynamically allocate memory and call it both from the constructor and from the operator =